# which SATA port maps to which /dev entry?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

I have an ubuntu box with 8 SATA drives, 6 on the mobo and 2 on an add-in card.  How do i determine which physical drive maps to which of the /dev/sd% entries?  it doesnt appear to be port 0 is sda, 1 is sdb, etc.  is there a file somewhere that shows this mapping?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in `/sys/block`, or run `sudo lshw` and look under your SATA controller.

Comment: you can also examine the output of *dmesg* for lots of additional details.

Comment: sudo lshw -c storage -c disk

Answer (score 0):

Try the [**hdparm**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man8/hdparm.8.html) command with **`-I`** or **`-i`** options.
There is also [**sdparm**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sdparm) (never tried it though).

Answer (score 0):

hdparm doesn't always work for me.  I use "smartctl -i /dev/sda" (or a-z).  I had to use smartcl on my USB based drives.  It may depend on your drivers/adapter being used.